# Scrollable elements slow in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've noticed that in Firefox, elements set to `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto` scroll quite a bit slower than the regular page scroll does. If you click on the top left Stack Exchange logo you can see what I mean if you use your mousewheel on the drop-down menu. Is there any solution, besides the about:config setting, to make these elements scroll as fast as the page?

This doesn't seem happen in Chrome, Opera, Safari or IE on Windows as far as I can tell. No idea about Mac, though (glad if someone could check/confirm).

Comment: Just did that in both Chrome and Firefox and they seem the same to me...

Comment: Okay, and you tried it in Windows? The thing is, I would need a site that I'm working on use the scroll on an inner div that takes up 100% width and height of the screen, and set `overflow: hidden` on `html` and `body`, but that would be kind of useless it some browsers treat scroll on different elements differently.

Comment: Any luck with this? My site visitors complain about the same issue...

Comment: Just to add a data point: I'm working on a UI that synchronizes the scrollTop and scrollLeft of two divs. Only the vertical sync (scrollTop) demonstrates what you describe (whether using mouse or keyboard) on Firefox 52 Mac OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan.

However, the problem in my case seems to be related to my syncing code: when I blank out the body of my function, Firefox works properly again. Everything works fine in Safari 10.1 and Chrome 57.

Answer (score 1):

Open Menu->Options->Advanced->General->Under Browsing Uncheck "AutoScrolling"

this should help

you could also uncheck the "Smooth Scrolling" option underneath. It only makes a marginal difference, but a difference nonetheless.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip, but it would be best if there was some CSS solution or anything. I know there are quite a few similar CSS solutions for webkit for when the scroll doesn't work as expected on iPad, etc. (`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` for example). I don't expect the regular site visitor to change settings in their browser.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a smooth scrolling plugin installed on firefox?

Comment: No, I don't use any such plugins.

Comment: you could try resetting firefox